Visual Studio Code in file Json about expand & collapse user interface problem
this is a problem about json display in visual studio code. where I am collapsing a property that holds an object but instead there are curly braces on the new line
i have a problem with visual studio code about expanding & collapsing json user interface.
This is a json where all properties with json values ​​are in an expanded state..
{
    "user": "Roxeyyco",
    "name": "Privacy information",
    "other_information": {
        "age": 17,
        "date_of_birth": "Privacy information",
        "height": "Privacy information"
    }
}

when I collapse the one property that holds the object, I get a json that has closing curly braces but is on a new line
{
    "user": "Roxeyyco",
    "name": "Privacy information",
    "other_information": {
    }
}

I just want (when I collapse the one property that had value object) the user interface in visual studio code to display the user interface like this
{
    "user": "Roxeyyco",
    "name": "Privacy information",
    "other_information": {}
}

